# Interchanging Limit and Integration

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $h(z_1,z_2):\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be a bounded function which is measurable in its first component and continuous in its second component. Then, for any $z\in\mathbb R$, there  exists (?) a sequence $(x_n(z))_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathbb R$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}h(z,x_n(z))=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}h(z,x)$ for all $z\in\mathbb R$. Let $\lambda$ be a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb R$. Can we conclude that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_\mathbb R h(z,x_n(z))d\lambda(z)=\int_\mathbb R \sup_{x\in\mathbb R}h(z,x)d\lambda(z)?$$ If not, what are sufficient conditions in order that one can interchange limit and integral? One immediately thinks of the Dominated Convergence Theorem, but I have the feeling that it is not directly applicable here.
In fact, in my example I have the following: Let $f,g\in C_b(\mathbb R)$ and $\psi:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be continuous such that $\psi(\cdot,y):\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is a homeomorphism for all $y\in\mathbb R$. Denote by $\theta$ the inverse of $\psi$ for fixed a $y$. Now let $h(x,y)=\sup_{\tilde x\in\mathbb R}(f(\tilde x)+g(\theta(\psi(x,y),\tilde x))$ and $h_n(x,y)=\max_{\tilde x\in [-n,n]}(f(\tilde x)+g(\theta(\psi(x,y),\tilde x))$ and the question is, if we can conclude that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathbb R^2}h_n(x,y)\lambda(dx,dy)=\int_{\mathbb R^2}h(x,y)\lambda(dx,dy)?$$ Note that I also posed this question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126316/interchanging-limit-and-integral).

Comment: The sequence $(x_n)$ depends on $z$ right? Maybe the notation should reflect that?

Comment: yes, you are right!

Comment: So I guess maybe one sufficient condition would be when a single sequence  $(x_n)$ can be chosen (I.e. not depending on $z$) since then it really is just DCT. But I don't know how helpful that is to you.

Comment: As it is it's not totally clear to me that $h(z, x_n(z))$ is even a measurable function in $z$.  So it seems like you'd at least need some conditions on the functions $x_n (z)$.

Comment: Perhaps, some of measurable selection theorems a-la those considered in Bersekas&Shreve can be of help here, if the undelying problem is a bit more general. Otherwise I agree with Tim, that you have to choose functions $x_n$ to be measurable. In such case DCT seems to be sufficient. So you rather shall ask youself of existence of such $x_n$.

Comment: yes, in my case I can use a measurable selection theorem to make the $x_n$ measurable, i.e. we apply measurable selection theorem to $x_n(z)=\arg\max_{x\in[-n,n]}\{h(z,x)\}$

Comment: @Ilya : The following link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268966/interchanging-limit-with-integral has a similar question, and there we need uniform convergence...I don't know if in our case  DCT is enough for the given conditions

Comment: Is in your case $h$ at least jointly measurable?

Comment: @Ilya: it is hard to say, since in my case I have $h(x,y)=\sup_{\tilde x\in\mathbb R}f(\tilde x)+g(\theta(\psi(x,y),\tilde x))$ where $f,g\in C_b(\mathbb R)$ and $\psi:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is a homeomorphism and $\theta=\psi^{-1}$. Defining $h_n(x,y)=\max_{\tilde x\in [-n,n]}f(\tilde x)+g(\theta(\psi(x,y),\tilde x)),$ what I want to show is that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathbb R^2}h_n(x,y)\lambda(dx,dy)=\int_{\mathbb R^2} h(x,y)\lambda(dx,dy)$

Comment: @AndyTeich: I see, perhaps it's worth putting this motivating underlying problem in the body of OP.

Comment: @Ilya...maybe I just change my question?