# Operation with limit and integral

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

do you know condition for which is possible to exchange limit with integral where s is real

$lim_{ s\rightarrow 0} \int f(x) e^{sx} dx = \int f(x) dx $

Comment: With indefinite integrals?

Comment: Also with indefinite but extreme are set

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When can the order of limit and integral be exchanged?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59363/when-can-the-order-of-limit-and-integral-be-exchanged)

Comment: Also [Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) and [Monotone Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem)

Comment: I think my question were simpler just as constant inside integral. Thanks anyway.